# Capistrano deployment problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

When I type

`cap production deploy`

I get

`Capfile locked at 3.1.0, but 3.2.0 is loaded`

When I uninstall `capistrano 3.2.0` I get

```
Could not find capistrano-3.2.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Me gemfile has

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
```

And Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
```

What to do in that case?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It occurs that `config/deploy.rb` has `lock '3.1.0'`.

It was enough to change it to `'3.2.0'` and now it's working.

Comment: `3.2.1` is now out. Is there a way to specify `3.2.*`?

Comment: As far as I know you have to specify particular version of capistrano.

Comment: @squixy You can use operators like `lock '>=3.2.0'`

Answer (score 8):

Shouldn't Bundler handle this for you? If you have the version specified in your Gemfile, you can remove the lock version in config/deploy.rb. Then a `bundle exec cap production deploy` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR:Capfile locked at 3.1.0, but 3.2.0 is loaded

open deploy.rb file
find:>>> lock '~> 3.16.0'
replace the loaded version to the current version
save and exit
now run "cap production deploy"
Enjoy!